# How to disable file reading in node js

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

i am using Heroku to deploy my project. In here, why CSS code can be opened(/index.html to)? how to disable file reading like this? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Lia.png)

Comment: Not possible if you want users to load these items at any point. In other words it's served to the public. IF you want it inaccessible to all users and only the server itself, that's all in how you code your setup and directories.

Comment: As a good example go load any site up, and go directly to the image or CSS file. It's just how it works the internet! Request city.

Comment: You can't. That's how the web works. CSS is used by the user's browser, so the browser needs to read it. If the browser can read it, the user can read it. I suggest you review MDN's [Client-Server Overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview).

Comment: How I make style.css or index.html only can read by Node js Server with express. so, if the URL is not on express request, nothing displayed @BGPHiJACK

Comment: You don't define it as a public folder for users @Niberthix. You would access it then with __dirname+"/privatefolder or something. It wouldn't be at all public this way and unsure what the use would be here. If anticipating an admin/private section you go about it differently.

Comment: Oh yeah, it works. but, CSS or design not loaded @BGPHiJACK, how to load CSS

Comment: Of coarse they won't load now, they aren't served to public anymore if you remove them like that. So your question how to load them, would be to set the directory public. No other way.

Comment: okay, so I am moving index.html to root directory and style.css on a public folder because the CSS file can't be hidden, SOLVED, how do I mark it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. The browser needs to access the CSS to style the page and blocking direct access to it prevents that.

Comment: so, I can't disable it?

Comment: Yes. If you disable direct link to the CSS then any form of usage will also be blocked. When you include CSS inside HTML, the browser would send a GET request to get the CSS (same way of accessing it via direct link).